# Spring: rest webservice call

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data

I am trying to append my query in the service url in my customerDoaImpl file But it is not returning correct value. I tried to test using soapUI on service side but there it is returning correct data to my request.

I am trying to Search result based on productId & datePeriod
Here is my code snippet-

```
  url.append(getServiceUrl()).append( "/transaction/find/customerrequestv2?id={productId}&dateperiod={Dateperiod}");
```

Service side Controller-

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/find/customerrequestv2", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = "application/json")

  public List<Customer> CustomerRequestv2(@RequestParam(value = "id") final String pProductId,
  @RequestParam(value = "dateperiod") final String pDateperiod)
```

What am i doing wrong in my query?

Comment: make sure you're encoding the query string.

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder `{productId}` and `{Dateperiod}` actually have to be substituted with real string, otherwise it'll get send to the server verbatim. For example, use string format:

```
String url = String.format("/transaction/find/customerrequestv2?id=%s&dateperiod=%s", productId, datePeriod);
```

Comment: Thank U sir for your quick answer.. Appreciate it.. :)

Comment: You are supposed to upvote the answer and accept it, if it answers your question.